# Zener diode noise power

Tags: diodes, noise

I want to design a noise source using a Zener diode, but I don't know which
a Zener diode i can use. 
Which a Zener diode have а strong noise?

Comment: define BW and strong,

Comment: And type of noise

Comment: Zeners are notorious for being noisy, except that this is a good thing for your application. Just drive a zener, AC couple to a high-gain op amp, and you're in business. Since you want noise, get the cheapest op amp you like. The input noise for the OA will add to the zener noise and you'll do even better.

Answer (score 3):

There are really two different things going on in a Zener diode, the Zener effect and avalanche breakdown. See [What is the difference between an avalanche breakdown and a Zener breakdown?](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-an-avalanche-breakdown-and-a-Zener-breakdown).

The avalanche process is much noisier than the Zener process, so you'll want to pick a diode that has a breakdown voltage significantly higher than 6V, where the avalanche process dominates.

Frequently, people use the reverse-biased B-E junction of a small-signal transistor as their noise source, because it shows a strong avalanche effect, and the parasitic capacitance is low, giving more bandwidth.